# Solution of integration of $e^{x^2}$

Tags: integration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you integrate $e^{x^2}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/215118/how-do-you-integrate-ex2)

When I try to integrate (indefinite)  $e^{x^2}$, supposing $x^2 = t$, and integrating by parts, the solutions seem to be never-ending. Is there any other way to integrate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use maclaurin series of $e^{x^2}$ to integrate

Answer (score 0):

No. It is well-known that there is no elementary antiderivative for $e^{x^2}$.

Comment: can i know why? And a glimpse of how can it be done in 'advanced' way?

Comment: By "elementary", we mean "elementary functions", such as taking powers and multiplying and addition. There *is no* expression for the integral $e^{x^2}$. We can only give it a name (specfically the "error function"). I don't know how one can prove this.

Comment: @akkkk: The error function is related to the integral of $e^{-x^2}$, not $e^{x^2}$.

Comment: @MårtenW: I must admit I missed that, but of course this can be solved by some appropriate complex substitution.